System Cannot Find the file specified when included in project, Visual Studio 2022
I'm trying to run a simple test in linking a C++ file
#include "MyFile.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Print();
}

where MyFile is simply
#include <iostream>

void Print() {
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
}

When I include the file in project in the solution explorer, I get the error:
Unable to start program
'C:/.../.exe'
The system cannot find the file specified.
However, it then works when I exclude the file from the project from the solutions explorer.

Visual Studio compiles all .cpp files in the project. #include the cpp files from the project will result in duplicate compilation and an error: one or more multiply defined symbols found.
If you exclude the file, MyFile.cpp will not be compiled repeatedly.
Unable to start programIt means your project did not compile successfully.
The project should #include header files(.h) instead of .cpp files.
MyFile.h
#include<iostream>
void Print();

MyFile.cpp
#include"MyFile.h"
void Print() {
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
}

Main
#include "MyFile.h"


int main() {
    Print();
}


According to the document: Linker Tools Error LNK1169

The /FORCE linker option tells the linker to create an executable
image (EXE file or DLL) even if a symbol is referenced but not
defined or is defined more than once.

Adding /FORCE:MULTIPLE  to the project properties -> linker command line options can alleviate this error.

@minxin-yu-msft I'm getting the same result after making theses changes.

Can you provide your build output message?

@Ozymandias In addition, Visual Studio has multiple property pages. Make sure you are modifying the one that is being built. There is active. Such as Active(Debug) , Active(x64). And build the project first, check whether it is built successfully, then run it.

I ended up creating a new project & it's working fine. I was also doing some changes to my versions of visual studio for some other projects so whatever the combination I did ended up working, though I have no idea how to reproduce it.
Thanks for your help!
